# Get All Points for a particular Tick value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am uisng `tickPositioner` to plot certain dates on X Axis.

```
 xAxis: {
 ......
 tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
                // custom function which returns dates array.   
                return  getDatesBetweenRange(min, max); 
            },
.....
}
```

using `Highstock v1.2.5`.

I also have Show/Hide series option in the Legend. It works fine no issues till here.

Now, When I hide any series from the chart. 
I do not want to show those dates on x Axis who have no data as the series is hidden.

I was looking into source code at "`getOffset:`" method where Label is being created for each
Tick.

Is there any relation in API which returns all series points for this Tick ? 
                                Or

Is there any relation in API that says that this tick pos (e.g. date) has no data visible ?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you can use a little different solution:

In tickPositioner you have access to all series for specific axis via `this.series`. Now, each of these series have `xData` which contains all x-values. All you need to do now is check if series is visible, and then compare your tick values (generated by `getDatesBetweenrange()`) with values in `xData` arrays - and return only these values which could be find there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So, For each Tick, I have to traverse series and check whether its visible or not. This may be performance issue for me as I may have 10-15 series. Can you draw any pointers to source code ? e.g. when Tick label is created or updated. I can hide it if series is not visible.

Comment: I mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/whrTH/3/ However I don't know how is your `gateDatesBetweenRange()` works, so this may not work for your case. I don't see difference between editing source code and using `tickPositioner` - in both cases tickmark on xAxis isn't connected to data, so you need to search on it own..